# How to place footnotes in rmarkdown html under specific header?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to place Rmarkdown footnotes under the header **Endnotes**. Whereas **References** can be placed with `<div id="refs"></div>`, that method seems not to work with footnotes, though. I opened the `html` document produced by Rmarkdown that revealed footnotes are collected under a tag called `<div class="footnotes"></div>`. I also tried `<div id="footnotes"></div>`, but that won't work either. How do I do this right?

## Code I'm using:

````
---
output: html_document
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don. N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.
  volume: 87
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## Section 1
Lorem ipsum dolor^[always look on the bright side of life] sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]. 

## Endnotes
<div class="footnotes"></div>

## References
<div id="refs"></div>

## Appendix
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
````

## Output produced:

[image]

## Expected output:

**Section 1**

Lorem ipsum dolor<sup>1</sup> sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua (Hawking and Page 1983).

**Endnotes**

1. always look on the bright side of life

**References**

Hawking, S. W., and Don. N. Page. 1983. “Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.” 87.

**Appendix**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a HTML document, JavaScript can be used.

For instance, this `Rmd` file renders as you want.

````
---
output: html_document
references:
- id: hawking_thermodynamics_1983
  author:
  - family: Hawking
    given: S. W.
  - family: Page
    given: Don. N.
  publisher: Communications in Mathematical Physics
  title: Thermodynamics of Black Holes in Anti-de Sitter Space.
  volume: 87
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 1983
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## Section 1
Lorem ipsum dolor^[always look on the bright side of life] sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]. 

## Endnotes {#endnotes}

## References
<div id="refs"></div>

## Appendix
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

```{js, echo=FALSE}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.footnotes ol').appendTo('#endnotes');
  $('.footnotes').remove();
});
```
````

Here, the JS script moves the list of footnotes in the `endnotes` section and finally removes the footnotes section.